# Delete recursive object entries

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class which looks like this:

```
class Foo{

    id:string;

    name:string;        

    childFooIds: string[];
}
```

Each Foo can store child Foo's by id, and I store all the foos in an object:

```
fooCollection:{
    [id:string] : Foo
}
```

I want to write a method which will delete a Foo from my `fooCollection`. I want to recursively go through its child `foos`, and their child `foos` etc. and remove them from my `fooCollection`. Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: Please provide example payload

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What about a delete method that does just that?

Comment: `When I delete a foo` - it's not clear what you mean by this. Delete from where? Delete from memory on a client? Are you deleting via an API call and you want to update your objects in memory on the client? Be more specific.

Comment: Updated my question to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am correct, fooCollection will look something like this

```
var fooCollection = {
 '1': new Foo('1','abc1',['3','4']),
 '2': new Foo('2','abc2',['6','7']),
 '3': new Foo('3','abc3',[]),
 '4': new Foo('4','abc4',['8']),
 '5': new Foo('5','abc5',[]),
 '6': new Foo('6','abc6',[]),
 '7': new Foo('7','abc7',[]),
 '8': new Foo('8','abc8',[]),
}
```

method to remove fooId from fooCollection recursively

```
function removeFoo(fooId){
  var fooObj = fooCollection[fooId];
  if(fooObj){
    for(var i = 0; i < fooObj.childFooIds.length;i++){
        removeFoo(fooObj.childFooIds[i]);
    }
    delete fooCollection[fooId];
  }
}
```

call it

```
removeFoo('1');
```

now fooCollection should look like this

```
{
 '2': new Foo('2','abc2',['6','7']),
 '5': new Foo('5','abc5',[]),
 '6': new Foo('6','abc6',[]),
 '7': new Foo('7','abc7',[])
}
```

Comment: @Alek does it help?

Comment: Thanks looking into it now, trying a solution I started to work on, very similar to yours. Will mark as answer when I get it working